# Json.NET wrapping JSON in quotes when using a DataTable Converter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, json.net, flot

I am trying to turn a datatable into JSON so that I can populate a Flot.JS chart.

I have the data in the datatable and can generate JSON using Json.NET but Flot isn't loading the data.

From what I can see the only issue is that the entire JSON response is wrapped in quotes. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
string jsonData;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strCon))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}


JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings   { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DataTableConverter());
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.None, serializerSettings);

return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

An example of the result that is displayed when I view the response in a browser:

```
"[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]"
```

Based on everything I can find I need to have the result in the following format:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4],[5, 6]]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think its because you trying to convert your data set to Json twice. Try return Content(jsonData); Or return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: That fixed the issue. Beginner mistake, I didn't even think about converting the data twice. Thanks!